# How can I prevent iterating arrays while trying to access multiple arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, html

[image]As seen on the picture, I am trying to display the error message without iterating it through 4 times. I have 4 arrays in total -> 1) $ansArray, 2) $qn_array, $four_qn, 3) $error, so I am quite confused handling so many arrays at the same time. Is there anyway I can display the error message if user input is empty?

```
<?php

    //to store 4 questions into a new array 
    $four_qn = array();  
    $message = "";
    $score = 0;
    //for lit.php 
    //$tick = "&#10003"; //for correct ans 
    //$cross = "&times;, &#215;"; //wrong ans

    $ans = array();
    //store the questions and into a multidimensional array 
    $qn_array = array(
        1 => array(
                'Question' => "In which novel of Roald Dahl, the character Willy Wonka can be found?", 
                'Answer'=> "charlie and the chocolate factory"
        ), 
        2 => array(      
                'Question' => "‘West Side Story,’ a musical is based on a tragedy by Shakespeare. Which tragedy is it?", 
                'Answer' =>"romeo and juliet"
        ), 
        3 => array(
                'Question' => "Who became the best-selling author in the 2000s in Britain?",
                'Answer' => "jk rowling"
        ),
        4 => array( 
                'Question' => "What is the name the novel by George Orwell where we find the character ‘Napoleon’?", 
                'Answer' => "animal farm"
        ),
        5 => array( 
                'Question' => "Tweedledum and Tweedledee are two characters of which Children’s book?",
                'Answer' => "alice in wonderland"
        ),
        6 => array( 
                'Question' => "Name the mega-selling writer who has written “Deception Point”?", 
                'Answer' => "dan brown"
        ), 
        7 => array(
                'Question' =>"‘A Brief History of Time’ is a famous book written in 1988. Who is its author?",
                'Answer' => "stephen hawking"
        ), 
        8 => array(
                'Question' => "Who ended his writing career with ‘The Last Tycoon’?", 
                'Answer' => "F scott fitzgerald"
        ),
        9 => array(
                'Question' => "What literary tale contains the phrase “fee, fie, fo, fum”?", 
                'Answer' => "jack and the beanstalk"
        ), 
        10 => array(  
                'Question' => "Theodor Geisel used what pen name when writing his children’s books?",
                'Answer' => "dr seuss")
    ); 
    
        shuffle($qn_array); //randomize 
        $four_qn = array_slice($qn_array, 6); //slice the array to get 4 elements and store into new array

    $formValid = true; 
    $errors = array(); 
    //validate answers 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $ans = $_POST['ans'];
            print_r($ans); //checking if values are stored into $ansArray
             
            foreach($ans as $key => $value) { //checking for empty strings 
                    if (empty($value)) {

                            $errors[$key] = "<span style='color:red'>" . "Please type something" . "</span>";
                            $formValid = false; 
                    }
                    else {
                            //all the input fields are filled 
                    }
            } 
    }

    print_r($errors);



?>

<body> 
<div class ="quiz">
<label name="Header" class="Header">Literature Quiz</label>
    <form method="post" action="lit1.php">
            <div class="Questions">
                    <?php 
                            //echo $message;
                            //echo the questions 
                            $count = 1; 
                            foreach ($four_qn as $QuestionNo => $qn) {
                                foreach ($qn as $value) 
                                echo "<h3>"; 
                                echo $count . ") " . ($qn['Question']); 
                                echo"</h3>"; ?>
                                

                <div class ="Answers">
                    <input type="text" name="ans[]">
                    <?php //display the error message 
                    for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
                            if(!empty($errors)) {
                                    foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                                            if ($i == 1) {
                                                    echo $value;
                                     }

                            }
                    }
                    $count++; //echo the question number to start from 1 
            } 
    }?>
            
                <div class = "submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check answers">
                </div>
                            
                <div class="attempt">
                    <input type="button" name="attempt" value="Try again">
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why foreach loop at all?  `if (isset($errors[$i])) {` then echo `$errors[$i]`.  Right?  No need to `!empty()`, no `foreach ($errors...)`.  Your code is a little too messy/rambling for me to review it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to worry about number of iterations when you are going into the thousands of array entries. Optimizing 10 entries or less per array is not noticable.

You can take a look at array functions in php:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.array.php

I wouldn't worry too hard about the inner loops, but in terms of learning, you can experiment with them to optimize your code. Also check the comments, some of them are oldies but goldies.

Some of the more interesting functions to save some loops are `array_key_exists`, `array_search`, `array_walk`. In reality these loop through the array for you, but at the very least makes for slightly more readable code.

**Suggestions:**

We can take a look at this loop:

```php
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
  if(!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
      if ($i == 1) {
        echo $value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You iterate here 3 times but only echo the `$value` on the first iteration. You can just remove the `for` and `if ($i == 1)` to achieve the same.

```php
if(!empty($errors)) {
  foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

- Think about using strings as array indizes and if that could help you. If questions worked like `$questions['q1']` and errors worked like `$errors['q1']` you can find the error to any question directly by the key instead of looping over all errors.
- Your `$qn_array` runs from index `1`. It is common to use 0-based arrays and loop from 0 to less than number of array entries. Does not make a difference, but be careful when applying examples from others. You run here from `1` to `< 4`, I hope this is intended.